# Is it possible to return search results as badges?

Tags: search-results, design

I'm trying to mock-up a custom search results page for a client, who wants to have search results from multiple lists, displayed as badges. Something like this:

[image]

How should I go about accomplishing this? I've looked at custom search web parts and they all seem related to the search itself (specifying search options), but not the results. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the xsl code of the search core results web part in the aspx file of the results page and get results displayed like you want to :)